# How to use add_rewrite_rule function to rewrite url

Tags: php, wordpress

www.ke6.com/text/month (The text is category name,cat id is 2)

www.ke6.com/?cat=2&score=month

my code:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^text/month/?','index.php?cat=2&score=month','top');
```

But it doesn't work.
When I visit it,actually it was www.ke6.com/category/text/.

Comment: What does your permalink structure say?

Comment: http://www.ke6.com/2013/11/sample-post/

Comment: Euhm, did you read http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks?

Comment: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url